# Iterate over very large array which is stored in a jonb column without loading it into memory

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, lumen

I have a table in a postgres DB which contains a jsonb column let's call it "data" that contains very large array stored as the following format

```
[
{
 "id" : 1
 "title" : "title 1",
 "description" : "description 1",
},
{
 "id" : 2
 "title" : "title 2",
 "description" : "description 2",
}  // etc... until 1GB of data
]
```

My eloquent model contains the following declaration.

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array'
    ];
```

If I use a statement like this

```
$array = $item->data;
```

It will cause an out of memory exception so how can I iterate over the array and preferably uses the cast in the model without loading the entire data into memory ?

Comment: My advice is to not store 1GB of data as JSON in a database. Store it as a table, if at all possible, and then you can use the power of the database to access it with minimal memory requirements.

Comment: This seems a rather severe violation of 1NF and indicates a much more significant design issue.

Comment: @AlexHowansky It stands to reason that Marcos DaSilva hasn't heard of 1NF. Perhaps a suitable link to [Database Normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) will help? There are many links to choose from...

Comment: I don't know much about Laravel or jsonb storage, but my _guess_ is that whatever you push or pull to and from the database is transported as a string, and then on the Laravel side `json_decode` is called. That function needs valid JSON, which means the whole string needs to be "somewhere", and if it isn't memory, I don't know where else it would be. You _could_ possibly look at using a [streaming parser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser), with the disk, but I don't know if you'll get all of the Laravel/Eloquent things you want then.

Comment: If you wanted to iterate over it in search for something, postgres has [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) you can use to delegate that to the db. With simple enough expression, it can even speed up further using an index.

Comment: **Do:** Normalize your data into proper tables. **Don't:** Serialize an entire table into a single field. I know that postgres has JSON functions and JSONB is a fun format with optimizations, but _actual tables_ absolutely crush JSON in every possible metric.